# Excel multiline cell import in SQL Server via ADODB

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, adodb

I have a field in Excel with comments. People enter data with line breaks in a cell (ALT + ENTER).

Is there a way via Excel VBA to import this via ADODB to SQL Server 2016, so I can also retrieve it again as multiline from the database?

An example: in Excel I have a multiline cell with value:

```
TEST

TEST

TEST
```

When I retrieve it again via the database it will show `TESTTESTTEST`, I would like to show the same as in Excel.

I tried both

```
rs![comment] = cell value
```

and

```
t-sql (simplified): insert into comment_table (comment) VALUES cell value
```

In both cases when I retrieve the data, I only get one string like in the example.

Hope somebody has an idea to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found the solution.

Field has to be of type nvarchar. If I query the table in SQL Server, I only see one string.

```
TESTESTTEST
```

If I for example retrieve it in Excel in a pivot and set the field to wrap text, it will apply the line breaks again.